# Counting Results Outside Channel Tag

Tags: channel, ifelse

I have this peice of code:

```
    <div id="slide-block1" class="flexslider">  
        <div class="slides">

          {exp:channel:entries
          channel="rotator-slides"
          disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
          orderby="random"
          dynamic="no"
          category="262"
          }
              <div class="slide">
                <a href="{slide-link}">
                  {exp:imgsizer:size src="{slide-image}" width="960" height="430"}
                  <img src="{sized}" width="960" height="430" alt="" />
                  {/exp:imgsizer:size}
                </a>
              </div><!-- /.slide -->
          {/exp:channel:entries}

        </div><!-- /.slides -->
      </div><!-- /#slide-block1 -->
```

The problem is that I do not want the first two "div" tags (and therefore the last two closing tags) to appear if the channel with that category has at most 1 entry. How do I get the total number of entries before using the channel tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it. I feel stupid. All I needed is to make a condition inside the tag!

```
      {exp:channel:entries
      channel="rotator-slides"
      disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
      orderby="random"
      dynamic="no"
      category="262"
      }
      {if total_results > "1" && count=="1"}
      <div id="slide-block1" class="flexslider">  
        <div class="slides">
          {/if}
          <div class="slide">
            <a href="{slide-link}">
              {exp:imgsizer:size src="{slide-image}" width="960" height="430"}
              <img src="{sized}" width="960" height="430" alt="" />
              {/exp:imgsizer:size}
            </a>
          </div><!-- /.slide -->
          {if total_results > "1" && count==total_resutls}
        </div><!-- /.slides -->
      </div><!-- /#slide-block1 -->
      {/if}
      {/exp:channel:entries}
```